# django ModelChoiceField: how to parse the initial data to map it to the correct value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I have a Form with a field that inherits from ModelChoiceField.
I use this Form in a FormView.
In the FormView, I'd like to set the initial value of the field by using the get_initial() method of a FormView but I would like to use a specific field of the Model, like `instance.guid`.

So how can I override the ModelChoiceField to parse the initial value that is used when the form is created to change it into a value the ChoiceField knows? (transforming my guid into the pk)

I would like to override the Field and not the Form. How does the form pass the initial to each field? It does not seem to be the initial parameter of the init method of the field.

```
# In a FormView
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(MyView, self).get_initial()

    initial['myfield'] = 'a guid string'

    return initial
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I actually found it, I had to override the `prepare_value(self, value)` method of the Field.